# 1. Please tell me the place where you want to visit tomorrow. 2. Please tell me the place which you want to visit tomorrow. Which is correct?

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns

1. Please tell me the place where you want to visit tomorrow.
2. Please tell me the place which you want to visit tomorrow.

Which do you think is more natural or likely to be spoken by native English speakers?

Comment: (2) is more correct, but in real life _which_ would probably be omitted.

Comment: In (1) it is unnecessary to use both "where" and "the place" - they mean exactly the same thing. You should omit one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Neither sounds natural to me.

I would say:

> Please show me the place you want to visit tomorrow.

Other possibilities are:

> Please show me what place you want to visit tomorrow.
>
> Please show me which place you want to visit tomorrow.
>
> Please show me where you want to visit tomorrow.